# Possible to use data from Powershell array to replace text in text doc

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, replace, find

I have a csv spreadsheet with 3 columns of data.
I need data from two of those columns that need to remain associated with each other.

[image]

IE: I need the data from Column A (TickerID) to remain linked with Column C (Rate)

That data then needs to be used to find and replace the Rate in a text file.

[image]

I have been able to extract that data with Powershell, and even have it show individual strings in the console but now can't figure out how to use it to then find the TickerID in the text file and replace the Rate.

What I have so far:

```
$csv = Import-CSV C:\folder\path\RateIDTable.csv | Where { $_.'Rate' -ne "" } | Export-Csv C:\folder\path\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
$bond = Import-CSV C:\folder\path\out.csv | select -Property TickerID, Rate
#write-output $bond[0].rate

$filepath= 'C:\folder\path\bond.out'
$match=$bond[0].TickerID
$replace=$bond[0].Rate
$content = get-content $filepath
foreach ($rate in $bond) {$Content -replace $match,$replace}
$content | Set-Content $filepath
```

The output shows the whole file contents in the console 3 times, and it updates one of the lines only (incorrectly, but it's progress!), but the text file content does not change, even though the file modified date does. I tried it with the file as a .txt as well, bu that made no difference.

[image]

I feel close, but can't quite get it to work. Once again, thanks for any help!

Comment: Whoops! I figured out how to write to the file. Had the variable in the wrong spot!

    `get-content $filepath
    $content = foreach ($rate in $bond) {$Content -replace 
    $match,$replace}`

But the rest is still bamboozling me

Comment: Your text file looks like it's a pipe delimited file.  Can you use `Import-Csv -Path 'C:\folder\path\bond.out' -Delimiter '|'`?

Comment: It looks like you are simply just replacing the line you have matched which is the ticker ID. I would suggest either importing the CSV file, or manipulating the document 1 by 1 and splitting the lines based on the delimiter.